# Check with Jquery if second level checkbox from categories are checked

Tags: categories, wp-admin

I have a two level list of Categories. First levels are multiple (more than 30). Also the associated child are a lot From the WP-admin, I would like to check whenever at least one of the second level (child) checkboxes are checked.   I will run the jquery function after the #post has been submitted. That part is easy, but how to check if any of the childs have been checked is impossible for me to figure out. Banging my head already for days :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this selector:

```
if ($('div#category-all ul.children input:checked').length) {
    // at least one of the child categories is selected
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I dont know, What I am doing wrong. There is my full Jquery code https://codepen.io/jamajamajaaama/pen/mdVBJjV  Two functions- 1. check if defined meta fields are not empty and second should check if at least one checkbox from custom taxonomy is checked. If both fails it should give alert to user and add error class to 'this' .  First function with meta fields works great. Second one not :(

Comment: @jam You want at least one subcategory of each of top level categories to be checked? Or precisely one subcategory of each of top level categories to be checked? Or at least one subcategory of any top level category to be checked? Or something else? As I understand, your code trying to check the first of these conditions. Check this: https://codepen.io/IvanShatsky/pen/ZEQXrmR

Comment: Or at least one subcategory of any top level category to be checked. That would be the correct one.

Comment: @jam One more question, you want an error if both check functions fails or if any of them fail?

Comment: If any of them fails.

Comment: @jam Updated codepen, please check.

Comment: Thats great!  Its working, thank you! Is ther any way on how to optimise checkCategories() function to define target categories once, not repeating multiple times. Just like checkMetaFields()

Comment: @jam Updated codepen once more )

Comment: You are awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Ups, this code allows to check also parent of child. Parent + child = true. Is there a way to allow only childs?

Comment: @jam That wasn't the scope your question, isn't it? Everything is possible :) Check the updated codepen.

Comment: Thank you once again! Everything working perfectly.

Comment: Ivan, Here I am again :) Apparently, wordpress display the checked categories on top of all categories and adds class  .popular-category to the parent li which contains input. I tried to manipulate If clause like this if ((jQuery('ul.children input:checked', catList).length) || (jQuery('.popular-category input:checked',catList).lenght)) {   but it is not working and fires error everytime.

Comment: Created a new codepen for this check out https://codepen.io/jamajamajaaama/pen/vYLVxLR

Comment: I figured it out, sorry for disturbing! https://codepen.io/jamajamajaaama/pen/vYLVxLR